# Как обновить кэш nginx при обновлении js и css файлов в nginx?

Tags: nginx

Есть сервер, где nginx выступает в качестве reverse proxy к бэкенду на NodeJS. Также там происходит сборка фронтенда с помощью Webpack, после чего в папку `dist` помещаются файлы:

```
app.iumgj87th88t7.css
app.87tbtn8tnt88n.js
```

Соответственно, когда бэкенд отдаёт nginx сгенерированный html, то nginx кэширует страницу на своей стороне. Если я выполню сборку клиента заново, то сгенерируются скрипты и стили уже с другими именами (хэшами). Но вот в nginx по-прежнему остаётся страница, в которой названия скриптов предыдущие из-за чего при загрузке страницы будут возникать ошибки 404 и страница не загрузится. Есть ли способ обновлять кэш без необходимости при каждом обновлении проводить `rm -rf /var/cache/nginx/*`?

Comment: А чем rm не угодил?

Comment: @andreymal возможно есть какой-то автоматизированный способ о котором я не знаю.

Comment: Я вот как-то не представляю, как автоматизированный способ вообще возможно сделать. Откуда nginx'у автоматически узнать, когда там nodejs свои страницы редактирует туда-сюда?